# Bit banging in ruby

Tags: ruby, security, bit-manipulation

I want to create a bit, that will contain security permissions for a given user.

In c#, I would do this by creating an enumeration, and then I would do some bit banging on the binary value, by anding '&&' to see if it results in a TRUE value.

How can I do this best in Ruby?

Comment: why do you want it be a bit field and not a hash or some other  level concept?

Comment: you mean bitwise and `&` not logical and `&&`, surely?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the underlying value is important then you can create a module that you use like an enum

```
module Groups
  ADMIN = 1
  BOSS = 2
  CLERK = 4
  MEAT = 8
  BREAD = 16
  CHEESE = 32
end
```

To set permissions just bitwise `or` them together

```
permissions = Groups::BOSS | Groups::MEAT | Groups::CHEESE
```

and to test you do a bitwise `and`

```
>> permissions & Groups::CHEESE > 0
=> true
>> permissions & Groups::BREAD > 0
=> false
```

I also like how you can make actual bitmasks more readable with `_` like this

```
permissions = 0b0010_1010
```

Comment: I don't understand the last part, what is 0b0010_1010 ??

Comment: It's the same as `p = 0b00101010`, it's just a way to make binary literals more readable.

Comment: You shouldn't make classes unless you plan to instantiate them. For this purpose you should use modules instead (`module Groups`...)

Answer (score 4):

Bitwse operations are trivial in Ruby.

```
> 1 | 2 # Create a bitmask from permission 2^0 + 2^1
=> 3

> 3 & 1 == 1 # See if the bitmask contains the 2^0 permission
=> true

> 3 & 4 == 4 # See if the bitmask contains the 2^2 permission
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Bates talks about using bitwise operations for embedding associations in this [podcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association). You can read text version [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association).