# Bitmasking alternatives in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I'm trying to achieve a simple use case, where I need to restrict a comment only to those users who are mentioned in it. I'm trying to use bitmasking in ruby to control the access. I'm using the stored 'id' value of users in the database to calculate the binary values.

[For eg, say example1@example.com's id is 140, I do a 2 ** 140 and store the hash. I allow access by doing a bitwise AND (&) with the hash and if the value is not zero. Please check this link:  [Bit banging in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867714/bit-banging-in-ruby)

Now, the problem is when I have bigger id values (clearly if id column is a bigint, bitmasking is a big no-no). Is there any solution to this problem? If not bitmapping, how else can this use case be approached other than an intermediate normalized table?

Comment: "how else can this use case be approached other than an intermediate normalized table? " - In a generic RDBMS, it can't. Use the n:m relation and head on.

Comment: *"bigger id values"*? `2 ** 140` already exceeds [MySQL's BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/integer-types.html).

Comment: @Stefan I meant if "ID" column is a bigint, bitmasking is a big no-no. (2**140 can be stored in a text column though.)  Calculating the powers will not even be possible is my point. Using an intermediate normalized table (as I have no other choice) with n:m.

Comment: @vijay that is correct, but unrelated to the column type. The bit-mask exceeds BIGINT once you have more than 64 users (or more precisely a user ID > 64).